# Why does Rails fails to boot with "Expected to find a manifest file in `app/assets/config/manifest.js` (Sprockets::Railtie::ManifestNeededError)"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

After `bundle update` my Rails app fails to boot with:

```
Expected to find a manifest file in `app/assets/config/manifest.js` (Sprockets::Railtie::ManifestNeededError)
```

Answer (score 124, accepted):

#### What's happening?

Looks like you've upgraded sprockets. The later version(s) of sprockets require what's called a `manifest.js` file. You don't have one. You need to create one, and add in a few "directives".

#### Why do I need to do this?

In the old version of sprockets, big assumptions were made about  what assets to bundle/concatenate** - this is what sprockets does btw.

"Sprockets, please"

- bundle everything in folder `abc` together
- bundle AND concatenate everything in folder `xyz`
- keep `admin.js` separate.

## Easy Steps To Solve the Problem:

1. **Create the manifest.js** file

   ```bash
   $ mkdir -p app/assets/config 
   $ touch app/assets/config/manifest.js
    (not the root rails directory)
   ```
2. Then **copy and paste** the following into the manifest.js file you just created:

   ```
   //= link_tree ../images
   //= link_directory ../javascripts .js
   //= link_directory ../stylesheets .css
   ```

#### What are "Directives"?

Those commenty things `//=` are called "directives".

If you haven't done so, pls review the [sprockets](https://github.com/rails/sprockets) documentation and save yourself some headaches. Small example below:

Let's translate the `//= link_directory ../javascripts .js` directive:

"grab every `js` file in the javascripts directory, concatenate them, and keep them as SEPARATE javascript files i.e. no bundling." If you want bundling, use a different directive.

#### Set up your layouts template

You should also have a `javascript_include_tag`, which is typically placed in your `application.html.erb` file. If you have other files js files that are separately bundled, don't forget to add them to `application.html.erb` e.g.:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application", "addOtherFiles", "here", "etc", "data-turbo-track": "reload", defer: true %>
```

3. If you have a precompile array in your `app/config/environments/production.rb` folder (see below for an example) then perhaps you should move them over to your `manifest.js` if they are not already accessed above.

   config.assets.precompile = ["admin.js", "admin.css"]

Presumably you will want your `admin.js` javascript file separate from your `application.js` file. No problem, just tell sprockets to keep them separate:

```
//= link_tree ../images
//= link_directory ../javascripts .js
//= link_directory ../stylesheets .css
//= link "admin.js"
```

4. Lastly, if you are using webpacker, you might want to decide what you want handled by the asset pipeline and what you want handled by webpacker.  i.e. remove the link_directory to the javascripts file according to your own particular use cases.

[Reference: read here for further details re: manifest.js. file](https://github.com/rails/sprockets/blob/master/UPGRADING.md#manifestjs)

[Source: Thanks to Richard Schneeman's blog - see here for more information..](https://www.schneems.com/2017/11/22/self-hosted-config-introducing-the-sprockets-manifestjs/)

---

#### Footnotes and Primers

- **Concatenating?** Normally JavaScript has a lot of white space. To speed things up, you can transform your JS code so that it has no white spaces, so it can be uploaded quickly - that's concatenating.
- And **bundling**? Not as important as it was anymore, but you can combine multiple JS files into one single file, and send that over to the browser). The latest changes are a step in the right direction: now you have to tell sprockets ***explicitly***, what files you want bundled and/or concatenated: this is done in your manifest.js file e.g.:

**EDIT:** if things are confusing / not clear: **complain loudly!** How can I fix if you keep mum? everyone benefits by these improvements.

Comment: Even though I have the file it stills says, Expected to find a manifest file in `app/assets/config/manifest.js`

Comment: Try restarting server. or `spring stop`. otherwise, i have no idea. please feel free to edit this answer when any of you solve it.

Answer (score 29):

A new major version of sprockets was recently released which is not compatible with the previous version.

Either perform the [steps needed to upgrade](https://github.com/rails/sprockets/blob/master/UPGRADING.md#guide-to-upgrading-from-sprockets-3x-to-4x) or pin to version 3.x in Gemfile

```
gem 'sprockets', '~>3.0'
```

Answer (score 10):

Based on the [answer here](https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails/issues/444#issuecomment-548526846) you may be able to solve this with:

```
mkdir -p app/assets/config && echo '{}' > app/assets/config/manifest.js
```

And if you need more details, [the answer in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58339608/1201134) helpfully points to the [Guide to upgrading from Sprockets 3.x to 4.x](https://github.com/rails/sprockets/blob/master/UPGRADING.md#guide-to-upgrading-from-sprockets-3x-to-4x)

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by link http://www.redmine.org/boards/2/topics/58169, it is a known issue. See #32223 and sprockets 4.0.0 breaks Redmine 3.4.11 with Ruby <2.5.0.

I just reproduced this issue with redmine 3.4.4, but found everything is ok with Redmine 3.4.12.

wget http://www.redmine.org/releases/redmine-3.4.12.tar.gz